# How to copy values from one MySQL database to another

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 databases with different structures.

I need to copy information from database A to database B.

Database A has 1 table while database B has 2 related ones.

It is a Q&A site so the old database (A) has a table that contains both the question and the answer.

In the new database these are separate and the answer must contain a field with the id of the question.

Please help me make a SQL request.

Something like

`"INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field3,field9)
SELECT table2.field3,table2.field1,table2.field4
FROM table2"`

One more thing .. some values in the new database are known (will be hardtyped .. not taken from the old database)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the below and specify manually where needed or grab it from the old database/table you are copying from. Also helps for if the columns are named differently or not as many in the new database.

```
USE `old_database`;
INSERT INTO `new_database`.`new_table`(`column1`,`column2`,`column3`)
SELECT `old_table`.`column2`, `old_table`.`column7`, `old_table`.`column5` 
FROM `old_table`
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify database in statement...

```
insert into database1.table1
select from database2.table2
```

Comment: I understand but how do I combine SELECT with VALUES and how do I use the LAST_INSERT_ID() for the answer link to question ID

Comment: You don't need VALUES() for "insert into select"... Just add WHERE in SELECT ... FROM

Comment: but some values are taken from the old database and others are hardtyped... how do I do that?

Comment: that depends on programming lang You use.... just replace field you need with lng specific parameter... for example, INSERT INTO tbl (fld1, fld2, fld3) SELECT tbl1.fld1, $xxx, fld3 FROM tbl2

and then in code add $xxx = 'some value'... again, that's language specific...

Comment: I think it can be done in plain SQL statements like:
`INSERT INTO tbl (auto,text) VALUES(NULL,'text');
INSERT INTO tbl2 (id,text) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'text');`. But I don't know the details. If I don't succeed I'll do it using PHP